# How to print external API on my server? (Take user ip address and show it on website)

Tags: json, node.js, http, get, koa

I have just started using nodejs and koajs, and I would like to take the ip address from here: https://api.ipify.org?format=json and paste it on my site or set it as a header. Right now I have the following:

```
        var koa = require('koa');
        var app = koa();
        var http = require('https');
        var a = http.get("https://api.ipify.org?format=json",function(res) {
              var data = "";
              res.on("data", function (chunk) {
                    data += chunk;
              });
              res.on('end', function() {
                    par = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(par.ip);
              });
        });


        app.listen(8888);
        app.use(function *(){
               this.response.set("userIp",par.ip);
               this.body = "ipadress: "; //this doesn't see par.ip;
        });
```

I know that I am probably doing something very wrong here but yea I am currently stuck because I have no idea how to take par.ip and assign it to this.body and set.

Would anyone be able to tell me how to achieve this or an alternative to the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the response from `api.ipify.org` doesn't change.

```
    var koa = require('koa');
    var app = koa();
    var http = require('https');
    var a = http.get("https://api.ipify.org?format=json",function(res) {
          var data = "";
          res.on("data", function (chunk) {
                data += chunk;
          });
          res.on('end', function() {
                par = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(par.ip);

                app.use(function *(){
                    this.response.set("userIp",par.ip);
                    this.body = "ipadress: "; //this doesn't see par.ip;
                });
                app.listen(8888);
          });
    });
```

Otherwise if the response from `api.ipify.org` constantly changes, you might to do the http request on every incoming request.